# La clase que hereda una clase ya no puede ponerse a otra clase que lo herede,

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

A la clase lo herede la primera clase class Ovas(Anime), pero después no puedo hacer que sea heredaro por un tercero que le puse class Peliculas(Ovas). ¿Solo se puede heredar una vez entonces?

```
 class Anime:
  def __init__(self, anime, manga):
    self.anime = anime
    self.manga = manga

  def animes(self):
    print("El anime es despues del " + str(self.manga))

  def mangas(self):
    print("El manga es antes del " + str(self.anime))

class Ovas(Anime):
  def __init__(self, anime):
    Anime.__init__(self, anime, mangas)
    self.ova = "ova"

  def ova(self):
    print(self.ova)

class Peliculas(Ovas):

anime_manga = Peliculas("anime", "manga")

anime_manga.animes()

anime_manga.mangas()

anime_manga.ova()
input()
```

Y una ultima pregunta, como hago para que una clase que hereda 2 clases, pueda imprimirlo con 2 self diferente, (self, anime, manga) y (self, anime). Porque al poner anime_manga = Peliculas("anime, "manga"), al poner un tercero no me sale.

```
class Anime:
  def __init__(self, anime, manga):
    self.anime = anime
    self.manga = manga

  def animes(self):
    print("El anime es despues del " + str(self.manga))

  def mangas(self):
    print("El manga es antes del " + str(self.anime))

class Ovas:
  def __init__(self, anime):
    Anime.__init__(self, anime, mangas)
    self.ova = "ova"

  def ova(self):
    print(self.ova)

class Peliculas(Anime, Ovas):

anime_manga = Peliculas("anime", "manga", "ovas")

anime_manga.animes()

anime_manga.mangas()

anime_manga.ova()
input()
```

Comment: Tus preguntas requieren una explicación más bien larga. Para una pronta respuesta, edita y deja solo la primera pregunta.  Creo que la respuesta a esa te aclarara las otras dudas.

Comment: Antes de responder a la pregunta hay que aclarar el modelo de datos y si realmente necesitas usar herencia. La herencia debe leerse como "es un tipo de". Así, según lo que intentas hacer, estás diciendo "Ovas es un tipo de Anime", y también "Peliculas es un tipo de Ovas". No soy otaku así que desconozco si estas afirmaciones tienen o no sentido, pero son las que estás haciendo con tu modelo de herencia (y la herencia múltiple del final significaría "Las peliculas son un tipo de Anime y un tipo de Ova **a la vez**"). ¿Son correctas estas relaciones?

Comment: Por otro lado ¿al inicializar una película tienes que pasarle parametros de Anime y de Ova? ¿Es una película ambas cosas a la vez, o bien es solo uno de esos dos casos? Quizás ayudaría que pusieras ejemplos con títulos concretos (y si en vez de ser del mundo japonés son del mundo occidental, por ejemplo Marvel, a lo mejor lo entiendo mejor)

Answer (score 0):

`self` es un parámetro que nunca debes usar en una **llamada**. Su único uso es para referirse a los atributos/métodos de un objeto. Este parámetro es llenado automáticamente por Python con el objeto en cuestión.

Esto es incorrecto:

```
class Ovas(Anime):
  def __init__(self, anime):
    Anime.__init__(self, anime, mangas)
```

y la forma correcta es:

```
class Ovas(Anime):
    def __init__(self, anime, mangas):
        super().__init__(anime, mangas)
```

Como tienes que llamar al constructor de la clase base `Anime`, tienes que pasarle los parámetros que espera (`anime` y `mangas`). Como no te lo puedes inventar, tienes que recibirlo como parámetro en el `__init__` de la clase `Ovas`.

También es conveniente usar simplemente `super()` en lugar del nombre de la clase base (`Anime`). Eso deja el código inmune si cambias la clase de la cual derivas.

No puedes usar el mismo nombre para un atributo y para un método, como haces en

```
  def ova(self):
    print(self.ova)
```

pues `self.ova` puede referirse al método o bien al atributo. Tienes que cambiar uno de los nombres.

Finalmente, una clase debe tener métodos. Si no vas a poner ninguno, coloca un `pass` en `Peliculas`. Si no tienes un `__init__` para esta clase, se ocupa automáticamente el método heredado de la `Ovas`.

#### Demo

```
class Anime:
    def __init__(self, anime, manga):
        self.anime = anime
        self.manga = manga

    def animes(self):
        print("El anime es despues del " + str(self.manga))

    def mangas(self):
        print("El manga es antes del " + str(self.anime))

class Ovas(Anime):
    def __init__(self, anime, mangas):
        super().__init__(anime, mangas)
        self._ova = "ova"

    def ova(self):
        print(self._ova)

class Peliculas(Ovas):
    pass

anime_manga = Peliculas("anime", "manga")
anime_manga.animes()
anime_manga.mangas()
anime_manga.ova()
```

produce:

```
El anime es despues del manga
El manga es antes del anime
ova

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: @DanteS. En qué sentido dices que `super()` no sirve para herencia múltiple? Te da un acceso al siguiente elemento dentro del mro, que está especificamente diseñado para herencia múltiple...

Comment: @abulafia pero que pasa si quieres llamar al __init__ de otras clases que no sea el primero del que hereda? No podrías con super.

Comment: @DanteS. Es que no se supone que sea así como deba usarse la herencia múltiple. Debe de ser "colaborativa", es decir, todas las clases deben usar `super()`para asegurar que no se rompe la cadena de llamadas en la mro. Aunque realmente nada te impide saltártela, en efecto, y no usar super(), pero el código sería menos mantenible y más acoplado. Mira por ejemplo [este interesante video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X1PQ7zzltz4)

Comment: @abulafia ahhh entiendo. Eliminaré mi comentario.